# Bitnami Let's Encrypt SSL installed - site is insecure

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, bitnami

On my AWS LightSail NodeJS server, I installed the Bitnami Let's Encrypt SSL certificate using the bncert-tool.

As per [instructions here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/) I also configured vhosts files:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/myapp-http-vhost.conf
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/myapp-https-vhost.conf
```

In these two files I changed the /opt/bitnami/projects/myapp/public to my app folder: `/opt/bitnami/projects/whiteboard` for example:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/whiteboard"
    <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/whiteboard">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
  </VirtualHost>
```

When trying to request a test html file on Chrome: `https://simplifylearning.org/test-wb.html` I'm getting the "Your connection is not private" page. Opening the certificate in the browser, it shows an expired **example.com** certificate - definitely not the SSL certificate we need to see.

These two commands return the exact same hash:

```
openssl pkey -in /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/simplifylearning.org.crt -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum
openssl pkey -in /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/simplifylearning.org.key -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum
```

In `bitnami-ssl.conf` file, there is this part showing my certificates:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/simplifylearning.org.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/simplifylearning.org.key"
```

Looking the `simplifylearning.org.json` file generated by the bncrypt-tool, it shows valid entries:

```
{
    "domain": "simplifylearning.org",
    "certUrl": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/cert/0419...d658",
    "certStableUrl": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/cert/0419...d658"
}
```

The cert files seems to have the correct permissions:

```
ls -la /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitnami root 5292 Oct  3 14:27 /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.crt

ls -la /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 bitnami root 227 Oct  3 14:27 /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.key
```

I restarted the apache server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

**Still - browser is not finding my certificate.**

Tried on other browsers to avoid cache issues: Brave and FireFox - same problem.

EDIT: Here's what I receive on the browser when I proceed to visit the website in a non-secure HTTP way:

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: you also need to set the full-certificate from the CA itself

Comment: What full-certificate? there is no CA here. This cert is issued by Bitnami and authorized by it.

Comment: You need to include your `ssl certificate ca bundle`  in your apache2 confuigurations

Answer (score 0):

Here is what was missing:

In this configuration file:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/myapp-https-vhost.conf
```

The SSL cert files pointed at were the default **server.crt** and **server.key** files, provided as samples by apache (with example.com as the owner). In my case, this is where they were pointed at:

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key
```

So, in the above config file, change the pointers to the Let's Encrypt SSL files generated for your website. In my case:

```
/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.crt
/opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/certificates/simplifylearning.org.key
```

It is unfortunate that this little detail is not mentioned in the documentaion and tutorials I followed, which were otherwise very good, especially this one:
https://github.com/joswayski/Lightsail-Setup-Custom-Domain-SSL